# Autoregressive process with random walk perturbation.

Tags: signal-processing, time-series, stationary-processes

Suppose we have an autoregressive process,
$$y_t=\phi y_{t-1} +u_t$$ where $|\phi|<1$.
If $u_t$ is an i.i.d random variable this process is stationarity. What if $$u_t=u_{t-1}+g+\epsilon_t$$ where $\epsilon_t$ is white noise and $g$ is a constant?
I tried to use the lag operator to show that it's still stationary, but I am having some issues.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The process $u_t$ is unstable so it doesn't have an autocorrelation; are could you give more information about what it is you're trying to do?